# How to find non unique elements in an array of class objects in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm not sure how to say what I need so here's an example:

```
class Foo{
int x;
int y;
int z;
}
ArrayList<Foo> a;
```

The array has objects `<a,b,c>,<a,c,d>,<b,c,e>,<b,e,f>,<c,e,f>,<g,h,i>` etc

How can I retrieve all objects that have a common x value. In the above example I would like to retrieve `<a,b,c>,<a,c,d>` and `<b,c,e>,<b,e,f>` only.

I'm looking for an efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through all the `Foo`s, adding them to a `Map<Integer, Collection<Foo>>` where the key is Foo's `x` value and the value is a collection of the Foos.

Comment: The thing is, when I find the first object, how do I know if I need it before iterating all of them? Do I have to do one iteration to "group" by x value and another one to find the "doubles"?

Comment: You'll have to iterate over all instances in order detect common x values.